# Is there an easy way to do a full diff between a sandbox and production org?

Tags: sandbox, ide, change-set, tools

I know I could use Mavensmate to diff each file, but is there a tool that can easily find *all* the differences in metadata between my sandbox and production org?

Comment: Eclipse can also perform this easily if you select both folders and `Compare With` > `Each Other`.

Answer (score 4):

**Shameless plug**: My team are building [Gearset](https://gearset.com) which provides exactly that functionality.

We have a 30 day free trial that will do what you want in about 5 minutes. No lock in and nothing to install in your org, so try it out and let me know if it works for you.

[image: Image of Org Diff in action]

Answer (score 1):

I've made my own in the past using the Metadata API and an external diff tool that can compare directories and their contents.

The basic steps are:

1. Pull down all the metadata of interest for both orgs to two directories
2. Point the external diff tool at both directories.

It isn't as refined as something like Gearset, as you can't then proceed to build a changeset. It does works in a pinch and can be extremely flexible.

An example folder diff tool is [SourceGear DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), but I'm sure there are tons of alternatives out there.

Answer (score 1):

**Shameless Plug:**  DreamFactory's Snapshot tool allows you to see a full difference of your orgs, and sort by difs, sims, or both.  You can also drill down into an XML view where  you can easily navigate from one dif to the next.

[image: Asset Snapshot view with XML Drill down. Profile view also available]